# $.ajax doesn't work in WP7 (Phonegap-Cordova-1.6.0)

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

i from Russia, sorry for my bad English Language.

Doesn't work $.ajax: dataType(json, jsonp) in Windows Phone 7.

**Zepto.js** - doesn't help.

Who met a problem? Help please.

**UPD 01.05.12:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" href="./css/core.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady()
  {
      //$.support.cors = true;
      //$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 

      $.ajax({
         url : 'book.json',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) { navigator.notification.alert('json success yeah'); }
      });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you provide more detail What have you tried?

Comment: i don't know what my next step..

Comment: help my problem, i don't know

Comment: Without seeing any code we will be unable to help you.

Comment: Hello, Jay! i add code for you.

Comment: Have you tried this in a desktop browser and used Firebug or some other tool to watch the request/response cycle?

Comment: The emulator will not give you true information that you need. You must test the process in a desktop browser and use a web developer tool to see what is going on in the request / response cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You lost type: in definition of ajax.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.0.2.2/mobileajax/callajax.php",
        data: ({name: theName}),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: onSuccess
});
```